# Firing trigger on compilation of a package body

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have a package body which gets updated regularly. I need to store few records(user_name, time, few-other-data) in a table whenever this body is compiled.

Is there any way to create a trigger that would insert the data in table when the package body is compiled?

Comment: You could add a few lines to the script that runs the compilation.

Comment: I am using SQLDeveloper, so not sure where to look for the "script that runs the compilation".

Comment: To me, your question seemed to suggest some automated process you wanted to log.

Comment: Whenever a package body is compiled, i want to store few information in a table. This is my question.

Answer (score 3):

You may create `AFTER CREATE` trigger on your schema. It will fire after each schema object creation, but you may limit what you log using functions like `ora_dict_obj_name`.

Take a look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96590/adg14evt.htm) to check what functions are actually available for `AFTER CREATE` triggers.

A sample trigger might be:

```
create table log_test (event_dt date, event_text varchar2(100));

create or replace trigger test_pkg_alter_log_trg
after create on <YOUR_USER>.schema
begin
  insert into log_test(event_dt, event_text)
    values (sysdate, ora_dict_obj_name);
end;
```

Creating such trigger will add overhead to any `CREATE` action, not just your package recompilation. It should be assessed if the overhead justify your needs. Oracle already comes with most (all?) events being logged, so I suggest you also look into for instance `DBA_AUDIT_TRAIL` view (events `action in (94, 97, 95, 98)`) to check whether it may be utilized for your purposes. Full list of actions in that view may be obtained by `select * from audit_actions`.